# knockout.js n-level binding navigation

Tags: json, binding, collections, knockout.js

I have this json structure coming in to knockout.js:

```
JSON
    {}
        Id=1
        Barcode=1234...
        DiscountLevel=40
        ProductCollection
            Id=1
            Name=Cool product one...
            Products
                {}
                    Id=1
                    Manufacturer=Cool Manufacturing...
                    ProductName=Foo
                    MSRP=19.99
                {}
                    Id=2
                    Manufacturer=Cool Manufacturing...
                    ProductName=Blah
                    MSRP=9.99
                {}
                    Id=3
                    Manufacturer=Cool Manufacturing...
                    ProductName=Boo
                    MSRP=99.99
```

The first level and second level (ProductCollection().Name) bindings are working just fine - data is flowing in.

I'm trying to figure out how to get a table of Products from the root.ProductCollection node.

Here's my current binding syntax (although I've tried many variants - including comment style syntax):

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: {data: offer().ProductCollection().Products, as: 'Product'}">

        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: Product.ProductName"></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

If you have solved this issue and would like to offer your wisdom, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Can you put together a jsfiddle of this (simplified) so we can see the code.

Comment: As @photo_tom suggest add a fiddle and maybe tell us what exactly isn't working. Do you get no output at all?

Comment: I'm getting output at the first level (e.g. - offer().BarCode), and second level (offer().ProductCollection().Name).

Comment: However, I can't seem to get at offer().ProductCollection().Products() to return ProductName from the Products() observable array.